# Any wordpress plugin image captcha with shortcode

Tags: image, plugins, wordpress, captcha

I am trying to use a Image Captcha plugin on my website.

Currently I am using google reCaptcha plugin with V2.

But I need a captcha with Image (like Flexible Captcha), I tried using it, but Image dosen't load for this plugin.

I searched for many, but I want it with short code, so that I can place it on my custom forms.

Or If anyone knows how to remove image issue with "Flexible Captcha" plugin, please post your solution.

**Edit:**

I also tried to use the **Securimage-WP** plugin as suggested by **drew010**. Following is the output of plugin:

On Admin settings for plugin:
[image]

On Login page:
[image]

**Note:**
My website URL is like ***http:abc.com/myWebFolder/***

Is this thing breaks the plugin to work or it could be the theme issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My plugin [Securimage-WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/securimage-wp/) offers a shortcode for putting a captcha on a custom form.

The plugin also defines a function which you can then call to validate the submitted CAPTCHA.

I have posted a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/dapphp/ab9016409535a6638816) which shows a WordPress page that uses the shortcode on a form and then validates the form and CAPTCHA.  Note: Since this page uses PHP, you will need a plugin (I use [Exec-PHP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/)) that allows you to run PHP code in posts and pages.

If you need to validate the CAPTCHA in a form processor that is independent of WordPress, you can hook into WP and the plugin by including `wp-load.php` from the root of your WordPress install.

Comment if you have any questions.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I tried to use your plugin, it is not showing image like the Flexible-Captcha, see edit in my post

Answer (score 0):

thank you **drew010** for your help, I made complete new installation of wordpress & used your plugin & it worked, then I also used Flexible Captcha plugin & that also worked. Then in order to debug the real problem I add my custom plugin code in new Wordpress. Then it braked. Therefore, to debug more I added each method in my plugin & tested it worked with method. The culprit was following code:

```
/**/
?>

<?php 
 function displayLoginForm() {

 /*
ob_start();
get_template_part( 'signin-form' );
$ret = ob_get_contents();  
ob_end_clean();  
return $ret; */ 
ob_start();  
include(ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/tus-forms/Views/sign-in.php"); 
 $output = signin_get_clean();
 return $output;

 }
 ?>
```

Changing above into following solved my problem:

```
 function displayLoginForm() {

     /*
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'signin-form' );
    $ret = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    return $ret; */ 
    ob_start();  
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/tus-forms/Views/sign-in.php"); 
     $output = signin_get_clean();
     return $output;

 }

?>
```

**But I still don't know the real reason behind this issue?**
but finally it worked.

Thanks

Comment: That code probably broke the image plugins because there was whitespace being output between the PHP tags in your first example.  Since rendering images requies the `header()` function to be used, the extra output probably caused those calls to fail.

Answer (score -1):

Captcha On Login This plugin is more flexible with image and its having another feature include of blocking ip and removing ip from blocked. I am using this plugin it is really good.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMXBh.png)